# the model "broke" after being imported into unity

Tags: animation, unity

To begin with, I tried to import a model that had no animation into unity, and everything was fine.

then I decided to create a small animation in blender and decided to import a model already with animation.And she..broke down(she became somehow transparent and the leg literally broke).

[image]

I suppose it's because of the meta rig, since the animation is hung on it, but why is it happening, what did I do wrong?

[image]

this is my first time working with blender, so I can't figure out where I went wrong

upd:

that leg...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like normal is inverted. It can be related to mirroring in X axis, because Blenders axis is right-handed, Unity is left-handed. So try to apply scale in Blender (Ctrl+A in object mode) then recalculate normals in edit mode (Shift + N)

You can also check normals, using face orientation overlay [image]

Parts with wrong normals will be red:

[image]

Comment: thanks, I solved half of the problem by applying recalculate normals (I didn't use scale because the model deformed horribly)

Comment: but the leg is still broken, how do I fix it?

Comment: try to select only the leg and recalculate normals outside Ctrl+Shift + N

Comment: Face orientation overlay should help you

Comment: mesh is normally displayed in unity (that is, not as translucent) when everything is red in blender, and when everything is blue, it looks bad in unity. But I was never able to fix her leg. I chose only this piece of leg in edit mode, but normals inside and outside did not help, maybe I did something wrong, please tell me

Comment: I then did such a thing that when recalculating normals, when everything turns red, the model ceases to be "translucent", but now the light in unity falls on it incorrectly. what to do?

Comment: This means that it has negative scale. Normal flips then -1 scale